# data from specific google spreadsheet tabs

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to query data from google spreadsheet with the general share link, but I want to pull data from specific tabs in that shared workbook.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question how you are querying a spreadsheet (there are several ways to do it).

If you are using spreadsheet data source url (e.g: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{ss_key}/gviz/tq?tq=...`), then you can add `gid` or `sheet` url parameters to specify which sheet in the spreadsheet to query by its id or name:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{ss_key}/gviz/tq?gid=0&tq=...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{ss_key}/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1&tq=...
```

You can get the `gid` number of a sheet from the spreadsheet's url when it is open in your browser. More info here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Google_Spreadsheets_as_a_Data_Source

***Note:*** data source url examples above are for **new** google sheets. If you are still using old sheets, the url format will be different: `http://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq?key=ABCDE&tq=...`. The documentation link above still uses **old** sheets url format.

If you are querying your spreadsheet via [QUERY() formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) in another sheet, then just specify the name of the sheet you want to query in the `data` attribute of the function:

```
=QUERY('Example Data'!$A$2:$H$7, "select A where (B<>'Eng' and G=true) or (D > "&A2&")")
```